# content query web part and multi select managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, managed-metadata

Was hoping this issue was resolved in SP 2016. I'm on prem with a public facing website.

I have 3 managed metadata term sets setup. I created a site column for each term set. I created both multi value select and singe select managed metadata columns.
With single select columns i can use cqwp to query the entire site collection and pull pages based on a term or any term within termset.

The issue is the end goal is to allow users to tag pages with up to 3 terms within each term set.
I've found the only way to use content query web part with multi-select is to point to a specific page library. In my case I need to query the entire site collection.

Is this possible with cqwp or any other web part for that matter? Are there custom solution options or is this a limitation with managed metadata?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Content search web part to show related documents taged with terms.

Per my test I create a term set called animals, then create a site column using Managed metadata type which allow multiple selection.

Then use this column to tag documents or items in root site and subsite, run a full crawl.

[image][image]

Add a content search web part> edit the web part> switch to advanced mode> use the managed property to filter the result as shown below:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Julie...very helpful, but I'm not quite seeing the same thing. I didn't see any of my crawled properties in property filter drop down. So I mapped a managed property to the crawled property and found it in property filter dropdown.
Property Name ows_taxid_MSGenCategories > mapped to property GeneralCategoryMS

Search query text box:
path:"https://www.sitecollectionURL.com" GeneralCategoryMS:Barrel Aging ＆ Barrel Maintenance OR GeneralCategoryMS:Brewery Safety

I'm not seeing any results and can confirm those values exist in a page.

Comment: I did get the search working GeneralCategoryMS:Barrel Aging ＆ Barrel Maintenance OR GeneralCategoryMS:Brewery Safety correctly returns 1 page. However if i add in an additional OR all kinds of odd results

1 result: GeneralCategoryMS:Barrel Aging ＆ Barrel Maintenance OR GeneralCategoryMS:Brewery Safety

2 results: MediaTypeMM:TQ Articles

1 result: MediaTypeMM:TQ Articles OR GeneralCategoryMS:Barrel Aging ＆ Barrel Maintenance OR GeneralCategoryMS:Brewery Safety

0 results: GeneralCategoryMS:Barrel Aging ＆ Barrel Maintenance OR GeneralCategoryMS:Brewery Safety OR MediaTypeMM:TQ Articles

Comment: Which i used first is Managed porperty,  please try to use ; instead of &

Comment: The & was part of the managed term. I replaced with the word and instead, but getting same results. Seems using OR with multiple terms is buggy